# Changing the polling interval on BizTalk MSMQ receive adapter

Tags: msmq, biztalk, polling

Is there some setting that affects the polling interval in a BizTalk MSMQ receive adapter?

I've read the section in Professional BizTalk 2006 that *"this is set to 1/2 second and is not configurable"*, but the delay on my test box seems to be about 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to have reduced the delay is reducing the Batch size down to 1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be possible to configure the polling interval for the MSMQ receive adapter.

With regards to the delay in polling of 10 seconds, is it possible that the Host/Host Instance under which the adapter is running could be heavily loaded, hence the delay?

Comment: Don't think so, this is my test box and I'm the only user